# Why don't "echo -e" commands seem to produce the right output?

Tags: command-line, echo

In the terminal of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, when I write this command:

```bsh
echo -e "Hello\\\n"
```

It gives this as the output:

```
Hello\n
```

But it should print, as the *man* page says:

```
Hello\
```

That is, first print `Hello`, then `\`, then a newline character (and then another newline). Where is the problem?

See these few [`echo -e` commands and their output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mQa0.png):

```bsh
man420@man420-X542UQ:~$ echo -e "HEllo\a\a\a\a\a\a\\\n"
HEllo\n
man420@man420-X542UQ:~$ echo -e "HEllo\\\n"
HEllo\n
man420@man420-X542UQ:~$ echo -e "HEllo\a\\\n"
HEllo\n
```

Comment: yes.for first 2 \ it should output a \.and last \ and n make a backslash escape \n(new line).so why it should print Hello\

Comment: Try it without the quotes.

Comment: An amazing answer was provided by Eliah Kagan, which you should accept.

Comment: Don't use `echo` in the first place: use `printf`.

Comment: See in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). tl;dr version: (1) `echo -e` is not functionality a POSIX-compliant version of `echo` is even *allowed* to implement at all (which is why bash turns it off entirely when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime flags are set); (2) for versions of `echo` that honor backslash escapes (which POSIX allows them to do *without* the `-e` argument, but also does not require), behavior is unspecified and nonportable; (3) use `printf` instead.

Comment: (or, rather -- the only 100% standards-compliant way `echo -e` can be handled is printing `-e` on output).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I very much agree that `printf` is preferable to `echo -e` (even when portability is not highly valued, and especially in nontrivial cases) but note that the confusion in this question is *mostly* about the effect of double quotes in a Bourne-style shell and which forms of quoting should be used in which situations, rather than the effect of the `-e` option that some `echo` implementations accept. *Double-quoting the first argument to `printf` would yield the same issues.*

Comment: Always use single quotes if you want to be sure that what you write is precisely what is passed to the command as argument.

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [Why doesn't printf escape newlines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564998/why-doesnt-printf-escape-newlines), [Why is a single backslash shown when using quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398646/why-is-a-single-backslash-shown-when-using-quotes)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Backslashes are treated specially by `echo -e`, but first they are *sometimes* treated specially by the shell (which in this case is `bash`), according to the shell's [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) rules.

**The argument `echo` actually sees is `Hello\\n`.** Because you have passed `-e` to `echo`, it treats backslash escapes specially, and `\\` is collapsed to a single `\`. The final `n` is not escaped, so it appears literally.

The reason for this is that, prior to and separately from the operation of `echo` itself, the shell [treats `\` specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) in some contexts but not others. Unquoted `\` characters are always treated specially, [single-quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) `\` are never treated specially, but the treatment of [*double-quoted*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) `\` characters, as in the command you ran, is more subtle and complicated.

When the shell encounters double-quoted text in a command, as with `"Hello\\\n"`, it treats `\` as an escape character when it precedes a character that can itself have special meaning inside double quotes *and not otherwise*.

1. Because `\` sometimes has a special meaning inside `""`, a `\` that immediately precedes another `\` has the effect of quoting that second `\`. So inside double quotes, the first `\\` are collapsed into `\`.
2. After those first two `\` characters, there is a third `\` character which is unaffected by those first two and which precedes an `n`. But `n` is not a character that is ever treated specially inside double quotes, so the `\` before it is not treated specially in this situation. Thus `\n` stays `\n`.

The effect is that, in double quotes, `\\\n` is interpreted as `\\n`.

When `echo -e` sees `\\n`, the first `\` removes special meaning from the second, so `echo` prints `\n` literally for that text.

---

**If your goal is to print `Hello` with an extra newline but no backslashes** (the question was originally ambiguous about this, plus I think it is a useful example), then one solution is to remove a `\`. Running `echo -e "Hello\\n"` outputs `Hello` with an extra newline at the end.

A better solution is to use single quotes and write `echo -e 'Hello\n'`. Single quotes are the strongest form of quoting. An even better solution is usually to use `printf` instead of `echo`, which in this case would be `printf 'Hello\n\n'`.

**If your goal is to print `Hello\` including the backslash, followed by an extra newline**, then the double-quoted approach is possible but cumbersome. To figure it out, work backwards: `echo -e` converts `\\` to `\` and `\n` to a newline, and double-quoting converts `\\` to `\`, so you can do it with six backslashes (`echo -e "Hello\\\\\\n"`), because `\\n` turns into `\n` due to one backslash escaping another. You can also do it with five, because double-quoting retains `\n` when the `\` is not escaped.

This illustrates the benefit of single quoting: just put whatever you want `echo -e` to see inside the single quotes (`echo -e 'Hello\\\n'`). `printf` is also good here. One option is `printf 'Hello\\\n\n'`. But where `printf` really shines is that you can plug in additional arguments. You can use `printf '%s\n\n' 'Hello\'`, which inserts the second argument (literally `Hello\` because single quotes don't change anything) in place of `%s`.